# WinForms controls are flickering when resizing on Windows7 x64

Tags: winforms, windows-7, 64-bit, resize

This very strange.

When I resize a WinForms dialog the controls are flickering very bad, some of them are disappearing. It happens only when using the application under Windows 7 64.

Comment: You'll have to post repro code to help us really nail this down.  Nothing to do with double-buffering of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for my problem is listed here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/11/20/controls-won-t-get-resized-once-the-nesting-hierarchy-of-windows-exceeds-a-certain-depth-x64.aspx

Comment: Nice background info! - pretty interesting solution involving `BeginInvoke()`.

Answer (score 1):

Double buffering is disabled in `Windows Forms` by default, and unfortunately you get this flickering issue as a result. It's a pain, but that's the way that it is. You may want to read the following, or provide some more information about your situation if these do not solve the problem.

- [Why is DoubleBuffered disabled by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408664/why-is-doublebuffered-disabled-by-default)
- [How to prevent a Windows Forms TextBox from flickering on resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333393/how-to-prevent-a-windows-forms-textbox-from-flickering-on-resize)
- [How to prevent flickering in ListView when updating a single ListViewItem’s text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form)
- [How to double buffer .NET controls on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87795/how-to-prevent-flickering-in-listview-when-updating-a-single-listviewitems-text)
- [Double-buffered Tree and List views](http://dev.nomad-net.info/articles/double-buffered-tree-and-list-views)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with onResize event and I finally could fix it adding Invalidate():

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
 Invalidate();
 base.OnResize(e);
```

}

I know that redraw the screen each time the event happens is not the wished way to do it, but it worked for me.